# How ScrollView detects scrolling events

Tags: xamarin.forms, scrollview

I am browsing the [ScrollView code in GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ScrollView.cs) and trying to understand how [SrollView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview) (Xamarin.Forms) finds out when someone swipes a finger across the screen of the device. I don't see any event responsible for this in ScrollView. I can see there is a `public Task ScrollToAsync(double x, double y, bool animated)` method, but what triggers it when I slide my finger?

Comment: the ScrollViewRenderer for each platform uses the native scrollview control

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [ScrollView.Scrolled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.scrollview.scrolled?view=xamarin-forms) event ? It is raised after a scroll completes.

The usage is very simple

```
      scView.Scrolled += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var x = e.ScrollX;
            var y = e.ScrollY;
        };
```